# Progress Bar Loop For Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, progress-bar

How do I insert a progress bar with a percentile calculation for the return of the table in html?

````
for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    
    var table_content = '<table><tr>'
    +'<td style= "font-size: 18px;" >' + array[index].value1 + '</td>'
    +'<td style= "font-size: 18px;" >' + array[index].value2 + '</td>'
    +'<td style= "font-size: 18px;" >' 
    + '</div>'
    + '</div>'
    + '</tr></table>';
    
    list_array.push(table_content);

    $("#div").html(list_array);```
    
}
````

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want ?

I don't know how to use JQuery so I used document.querySelector() 
I've added a timeout to let you see that it is working

```js
const array = [
  {
    value1: '1',
    value2: '2',
  },
  {
    value1: '3',
    value2: '4',
  },
  {
    value1: '5',
    value2: '6',
  },
]

for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      var table_content = '<table><tr>'
      +'<td style= "font-size: 18px;" >' + array[index].value1 + '</td>'
      +'<td style= "font-size: 18px;" >' + array[index].value2 + '</td>'
      +'<td style= "font-size: 18px;" >' 
      + '</div>'
      + '</div>'
      + '</tr></table>';

      document.querySelector('#div').innerHTML += table_content
      document.querySelector('#progress-bar').value = (index+1)/array.length*100
    }, (index+1) * 1000)
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
<progress id="progress-bar" value="0%" max="100" />
```